# How To Setup Domain Name for SchoolTool Local Server

Tags: 11.10, networking, home-server

I am currently testing [SchoolTool 2.0](http://www.schooltool.org) and I would like to do some things:

This application is installed on a virtual machine running Ubuntu Server 11.10 bridged to our home network. The site is accessible through IP address.

What I would like to do is setup a local domain, say schooltool.ourhomedomain.com. I thought my sister would appreciate it more if it were not via IP address.

If there's anymore information needed, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If this is a local network, then you can use hostname.local to access the VM. For instance, if the VMs hostname is st, and you're connecting through a web browser, you can use http://st.local to access it without any setup. This will only be available on the local network. If you would like to change the hostname, that is done by simply editing the file /etc/hostname which only contains the hostname. In order to do so, press alt+f2 and enter `gksu gedit /etc/hostname`. You'll need to reboot for the change to be used.

If this should be available globally, then you'll need to add a DNS server, such as bind, and edit the zone file. You can read more about that here: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/dns.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user friendly URL by creating an entry on your DNS server that resolves the IP address to the friendly URL of your choosing. The way to do that is dependent on the DNS server that you are running on your network. Alternatively, if you are not running a DNS server, other methods such as host file may be used. Need more details in order to provide a more specific answer if required.